# How could we find preons?

Tags: experimental-physics, quarks, beyond-the-standard-model

If I understand correctly, scientists were able to find strong evidence for the existence of quarks by using [deep inelastic scattering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deep_inelastic_scattering). If quarks (hypothetically) are composed of [preons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preon), could we use similar methods to detect the preons? If so, how would we have to modify the scattering experiments used to detect quarks?

Comment: We would do the usual and crank up the energy.