# What's inside a quark?

Tags: quarks, beyond-the-standard-model

What particles make up a [quark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quark)? We all know quarks (**3, uud**) make up a proton.  I read on Wikipedia they are called "hadrons" ,but how do they work?

Is the collection wave functions of the components of the quark representative of the wavefunction of the quark itself?

Comment: You misunderstood - quarks make up the *hadrons* like protons and neutrons. We don't know if there's anything making up the quarks, but there's no evidence indicating that they possess substructure.

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/16048/2451 , http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/141554/2451 and links therein.

Comment: Ooh, you're right @ACuriousMind... Protons and neutrons are hadrons.

Comment: elementary particles are point particles by all indications of our experiments and the theoretical models that fit and predict their behavior. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Model

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You got that the wrong way around. Hadrons are made up of quarks. There are different types of hadrons, e.g. baryons (3 quarks) and mesons (1 quark, 1 antiquark). So a proton is just one special type of baryon and therefore also a hadron.

Now what quarks are made up of is not a sensible question in the frame we use to think about particle physics nowadays. Quarks are the smallest units or building blocks of the [Standard Model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Model) of particle physics and therefore cannot be split up into further constituents.

On the other hand, if one chooses to believe in [string theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_theory), basically everything is made up of tiny vibrating strings, including quarks.

Comment: So if If i have understood clearly: quarks are the smallest particles possible and and are fixed points and thus have no possible wavefunction associated to them? But if string theory proves to be true, quarks are made up of tiny vibrating strings?

Comment: no, pointlike particles definitley can have a wavefunction. Electrons do, for example

Comment: Yes, if you will quarks are the smallest particles possible, together with all the other fundamental particles of the SM, that is leptons (e.g. electrons, neutrinos) as well as bosons (e.g. photon, Higgs). They can be described in terms of  wavefunctions, just as electrons can. And I guess to say particles "are made up of strings" is a bit sloppy. The correct statement would be that particles are excitations of degrees of freedoms of string theory. If string theory will/can be proven to be true or false is a whole different issue.

Comment: It might be better to say that quarks (and leptons, etc) behave as point-like particles down to the smallest dimension that we can currently measure.  That doesn't mean that they are point-like, but it does mean that for all practical purposes today, they can be treated as points.  In the future, internal structure may be discovered.  The theory that describes that structure might be string theory, but it might be something else.  There's no reason to single out string theory in this highly speculative discussion.

Comment: Is there any particular behaviour associated with pont-like particles? (Classical mechanics or other)

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_particle